# Using vert.x async mongo client with spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-mongodb, vert.x

I would like to use a combination of :

- `spring data mongodb`
- and [vertx-mongo-client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mongo-client/java/)

To support resp `@DBRef` from spring data and async MongoDB access from vertx-mongo-client

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to combine both. If yes, how?
2. If no, how can I use `@DBRef` with vertx-mongo-client?

Thanks!

Comment: The best advice here is to not use `DBRef` at all. It was really never anything than an old "hack" at providing some sort of "join" functionality and then only in drivers which implemented code to do such a *"pseudo join"*. Modern implementations ( as in, for many more years than before and the `DBRef` "hack" was suggested ) have [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). So you should really learn how to use that. Or better yet, model so you don't use relational joins at all.

Comment: ```DBRef``` is not deprecated. My project use spring data, and I can't unwrap it yet

Comment: It may not be officially deprecated but's it's just a generally bad idea. This is **not a join**. All it is and ever was, is simply an indicator to *some* ( an increasingly smaller number ) of driver implementations to go an execute another query to fetch some "related" data. `$lookup` has superceeded that "hackery" for many years now. And as alluded to earlier, MongoDB really should not be treated **primarily** as a relational datastore. Also, you might consider looking at the profile page of people you respond to before you point them to the manual :)

Comment: Thanks Neil. For more info about your point, here is a link: https://www.compose.com/articles/mongodb-and-the-trouble-with-dbrefs/
I may rewrite the current implementation to use manual references (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#manual-references) and post the result here.